# PostgreSQL performance tuning under heavy load

Tags: postgresql, system, database-administration

My Server has following resources :

```
[postgres@srv2813 ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15929      15118        810        142         12        219
-/+ buffers/cache:      14885       1043
Swap:         8031       2007       6024



[postgres@srv2813 ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
    8



[root@srv2813 postgres]# sysctl kernel.shmall
kernel.shmall = 4194304
[root@srv2813 postgres]# sysctl kernel.shmmax
kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
```

and My PostgreSQL conf :

```
default_statistics_target = 100
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 12GB
work_mem = 32MB
wal_buffers = 16MB
shared_buffers = 3840MB
max_connections = 500
fsync = off
temp_buffers=32MB
```

But its getting "too many connection" error. The `nginx_status` page of the webserver shows around 500 active connections when this happens. The server hosts an api severver, so every "http request" invariably initiate a database "read". Its not a "write" heavy thing, but very "read" heavy.

Its possible that i maxed out our sever, but still i expected a little more from a 16G/8 core box considering the "read only" nature of the application. Can i push the PostgreSQL in any other possible direction?

Comment: 16GB/8 Core is not really a "big box" - and definitely not  a "high end" DB server. That's more the size of a well equipped PC or Notebook. But you should really look into connection pooling as Matt suggested. Either inside your application or using something like pgBouncer  or pgPool

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is process based vs thread based so it does not generally work well with a lot of connections.

I would look at using something like PgBouncer. PgBouncer is a lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL.